# Could not find jenkins_home folder in Ubuntu after downloading the Docker Jenkins Image

Tags: jenkins, docker, jvm

I pulled Docker-Jenkins image from Docker central repository and run the below command

```
$ docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 Jenkins
```

In the middle of the installation, the below lines appeared.

```
*************************************************************************`
Jenkins initial setup is required. An admin user has been created and a password generated.
Please use the following password to proceed to installation:
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
This may also be found at: /var/jenkins_home/secrets/initialAdminPassword
*************************************************************************`
```

But in my `/var`, no `jenkins_home` folder is present.

I am getting the following error and I couldn't access my Jenkins using `localhost:8080`

> INFO: Jenkins is fully up and running
>   Oct 11, 2016 4:31:19 AM winstone.Logger logInternal
>   INFO: JVM is terminating. Shutting down Winstone

When the Admin password got generated, I was able to access the Jenkins Dashboard. But immediately, JVM is getting terminated and I can no longer access the Jenkins page.

Comment: The folder `/var/jenkins_home` is _in_ your docker-container, not on your host.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am new to Ubuntu.
Can you help me in mapping the container to the host?

Comment: Thats done with the `-v` option for docker. If you want to map the contailers `/var/jenkins_home/` to the hosts `/var/jenkins_home/` then `-v /var/jenkins_home/:/var/jenkins_home/` should work.

Comment: touch: cannot touch ‘/var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log’: Permission denied
Can not write to /var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log. Wrong volume permissions?

This is the error i am getting when i tried " -v /var/jenkins_home/:/var/jenkins_home/ "

Answer (score 28):

After starting jenkins you have 2 choices:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -d -p 50000:50000 jenkins
```

(The `-d` option is to run the container in the background)
You can go inside the container and checking the initial admin passwd:
check running containers

```
[root@localhost ~]# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                              NAMES
cc73eb6d6f75        jenkins             "/bin/tini -- /usr/lo"   32 seconds ago      Up 30 seconds       0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:50000->50000/tcp   ecstatic_leakey
```

Go inside the container

```
docker exec -it cc73eb6d6f75 bash
```

And check the content of the adminpasswd

```
jenkins@cc73eb6d6f75:/$ cat /var/jenkins_home/secrets/initialAdminPassword
1c8be33b31904cacb5xxx
```

Or you create your own named docker volume:

```
[root@localhost ~]# docker volume create --name jenkins-volume
jenkins-volume
```

This volume is on your host in `/var/lib/docker/volumes/jenkins-volume`.
You can start your jenkins and connect it with the volume:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -d -p 50000:50000 -v jenkins-volume:/var/jenkins_home jenkins
```

All the data from `/var/jenkins_volume` inside your container will be mounted inside your named volume. hostpath is: `/var/lib/docker/volumes/jenkins-volume/_data`

So check on my host:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ls /var/lib/docker/volumes/jenkins-volume/_data
config.xml               hudson.model.UpdateCenter.xml   init.groovy.d                                jobs              nodes          secret.key                updates      war
copy_reference_file.log  hudson.plugins.git.GitTool.xml  jenkins.install.InstallUtil.lastExecVersion  logs              plugins        secret.key.not-so-secret  userContent  workspace
credentials.xml          identity.key.enc                jenkins.install.UpgradeWizard.state          nodeMonitors.xml  queue.xml.bak  secrets                   users
```

Answer (score 4):

If you installed via the [Jenkins Docker official instructions](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/installing), the `jenkins-data` Docker volume gets automatically created in the run command. So to get the password:

```
sudo cat /var/lib/docker/volumes/jenkins-data/_data/secrets/initialAdminPassword
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mount a host dir as `jenkins_home` you need to give the Jenkins user (UID 1000) ownership of that dir.

`JENKINS_HOME=/home/$(whoami)/jenkins_home
mkdir $JENKINS_HOME
chown -R 1000 $JENKINS_HOME`

Run Jenkins container:

`docker run -d --name jenkins \ 
    -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 \ 
    -v /home/$(whoami)/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home \ 
    jenkins`

You can find a detailed walkthrough [here](https://stefanprodan.com/2016/continuous-integration-with-jenkins-and-disposable-containers/) on how to run Jenkins CI from a container.